# Access to Incendiary Aura without playing Oracle?

Tags: pathfinder-2e

Are there any possible ways to get access to [Incendiary Aura](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=755) without:

1. Using the Oracle class (with Flames mystery)
2. Using the Oracle archetype (Oracle Dedication with  Flames mystery + First Revelation)

?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Most likely not.

It's hard to prove a negative, but I don't know of anything that gives you focus spells without being the specific class these spells are for. In your case, it also does not matter, because you could not cast the spell anyway, even if you were to get it from somewhere.

The spell has the [Cursebound](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=320) trait, which includes this line:

> You can't cast a cursebound spell if you don't have an oracular curse.

So you would need to have the curse if you want to cast this spell. And there is also no way to get that without the oracle class (or archetype).